# vue-i18n how to set default variable for formatting?

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

format

```js
const messages = {
  en: {
    message: {
      hello: '{msg} world'
    }
  }
}
```

usage

```html
<p>{{ $t('message.hello', { msg: 'hello' }) }}</p>
<!-- I don't want to input the second param {msg: 'hello'} -->
```

how can I set the default value for 'msg' and no need to input `{msg: 'hello'}` in every `$t` function?

Comment: Don’t use a placeholder in places where you don’t want a placeholder. Add a translation with default message and use it when you want to use a default message.

Comment: Main purpose of using interpolation `{msg}` in the message properties to make it dynamic, But if you want static content then you can directly use 'Hello' instead of `{msg}` in the language file or you can get the Hello string from the central store.

Answer (score 0):

You can define two messages:

```js
const messages = {
  en: {
    message: {
      world: '{msg} world',
      helloWorld: 'Hello world'
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```html
<!-- Use the translation without format syntax -->
<p>{{ $t('message.helloWorld' }}</p>
<!-- result: <p>Hello world</p> -->

<!-- Input the second param when you need it -->
<p>{{ $t('message.world', { msg: 'Goodbye' }) }}</p>
<!-- result: <p>Goodbye world</p> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create yourself a custom `$t2` method (or alike), which supersets the basic `$t` with a default param injection.
Clearly not sure that it's worth the hassle since it will not benefit from i18n's devtools hints (which are quite handy for sure) and is not worth the "time gained".

I'd stick to regular approach and put the effort into writing that manually when needed. Or stick to a hardcoded approach if no variable is needed.

Answer (score -2):

I found the method.

use [Linked messages](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/essentials/syntax.html#linked-messages)

defined the default value and use in each text

```js
{
  name: 'Jacky',
  variable: 'Hello @:name' 
}
```

Comment: That is not a "default" value because now you cannot pass a second param to `${t('variable')}` to replace `Jacky`